# Why will this circuit not work? I need a perfect reason

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, circuit-design, electronic-load

Will this bulb light for nanoseconds?

[image]

Comment: You're showing us a "hookup" diagram instead of a circuit.If you want an answer, include a circuit. What does "light for nanoseconds" mean?

Comment: Are there any reasons you thought of that turned out to be imperfect?

Comment: Anyway, OP, there is an effort requirement for school questions.  You can read about it in the Tour under Electrical Engineering at the bottom left of the screen.  When you post a school question here, include your attempt (in this case tell us why you think the light might turn on and why you think it might not probably) and you won't be so likely to catch a bunch of downvotes and close votes.  If you can't provide an attempt, say add that you're having trouble getting started to your question and someone can give guidance without giving away the answer.

Comment: Half of your "circuit" is on the backside of your board and is a mystery to us. It is not even clear how your light (no details provided) is connected. If you want a perfect answer, provide a perfect question.

Comment: Are you about to do a magic trick or something cz you have hidden most of the circuit from us.

Comment: how many nanoseconds? ... don't be thinking that `for nanoseconds` means a short time ... a century can also be expessed in nanoseconds

Comment: @Barry I don't think there's anything on the back side of the board.

Comment: No Loop shown.   and light needs heat for a bulb which needs time to rise.  How hot is 2500'K?

Comment: If it did light for ns, you would not even see it, so how is that relevant to the question.

Answer (score 4):

Since this looks like schoolwork I will just provide a hint.

From the dictionary.

> #### circuit
>
> /ˈsəːkɪt/
> *noun*
>
> 1. a roughly circular line, route, or movement that starts and finishes at the same place.

Does what you have drawn look like a circuit? Figure that out and you'll have a perfect reason.